# Как настроить apache для SPA?

Tags: apache

Есть Single Page App на VUE JS с роутингом на клиенте.
Настройки Apache в файле .htaccess выглядят вот так:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>`
```

Все переходы по ссылкам внутри сайта работают, если ты переходишь с главной.
Но если зайти по прямой ссылке(mysite.com/anotherpage)
не на главную страницу выдает 404

Как настроить apache чтобы сразу попадать на нужный роут?

Answer (score 0):

Я настроил у себя так для Angular приложения, сразу перенаправляет на https и не ломается при перезагрузке

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.html?/$1 [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.html?/$1 [L]
    ErrorDocument 404 index.php
```